# Why were randomly chosen questions with good votes down voted within a very short time?

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes

Today something strange happened to some of my questions. Within a very short time (almost instantly) someone down voted three of my questions which all have been up voted before or were of interest to people.

Strangely some of these questions where asked years ago and are not connected to each other in any kind of way.

For me this seems like someone randomly down voted my questions.

Is there a way to figure out who down voted and why?

Comment: There's no way to figure it out. Given enough downvotes by a single person in a short period the system will revert them at the end of the day. Otherwise if there's a pattern over several days of multiple votes per day you could try flagging. For 3 votes it's not worth getting a mod involved though.

Comment: I see. this makes sense ...

Answer (score 2):

> For me this seems like someone randomly down voted my questions.

Could be. But you don't know that, and you can't know that. If someone is purposefully and serially targeting you for downvotes, the script that runs every night to catch that will reverse it.

> Is there a way to figure out who down voted and why?

Nope, downvotes are anonymous and downvoters are not required to provide a reason.

My advice is to just let it go. If it ever becomes a serious issue, the script will pick it up and catch it. If not, -6 rep is nothing to fret about too much.